# Pushing app on heroku fails - rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy the app Catarse on heroku, but it does not want to push it.
I am quite new to git and heroku, so perhaps I am just making a very stupid basic error, but still..

This is what I got:

```
 git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1740, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1657/1657), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1740/1740), 4.90 MiB | 356.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1740 (delta 308), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:        Detected buildpacks: Ruby, Node.js
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/catarse/catarse_api.git
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/catarse/moip-ruby.git
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/catarse/redactor-rails.git
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing CFPropertyList 2.3.1
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing minitest 5.7.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing rack 1.5.5
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.1
remote:        Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing addressable 2.3.8
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing extlib 0.9.16
remote:        Installing rinku 1.5.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.0
remote:        Installing browser 0.8.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing crack 0.1.8
remote:        Installing redcarpet 3.2.3
remote:        Installing excon 0.45.3
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Installing netrc 0.10.3
remote:        Installing weekdays 1.0.2
remote:        Installing libxml-ruby 2.8.0
remote:        Installing chartkick 1.3.2
remote:        Installing chunky_png 1.3.4
remote:        Installing cocoon 1.2.6
remote:        Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.5.2
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.15
remote:        Installing rb-fsevent 0.9.4
remote:        Installing connection_pool 2.2.0
remote:        Installing hitimes 1.2.2
remote:        Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
remote:        Installing jwt 1.5.1
remote:        Installing little-plugger 1.1.3
remote:        Installing memoist 0.12.0
remote:        Installing retriable 1.4.1
remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Installing oauth 0.4.7
remote:        Installing multi_xml 0.5.5
remote:        Installing temple 0.7.6
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing request_store 1.1.0
remote:        Installing ezcrypto 0.7.2
remote:        Installing sax-machine 1.3.2
remote:        Installing formatador 0.2.5
remote:        Installing net-ssh 2.9.2
remote:        Installing ipaddress 0.8.0
remote:        Installing inflecto 0.0.2
remote:        Installing hashie 3.4.1
remote:        Installing high_voltage 2.3.0
remote:        Installing htmlentities 4.3.3
remote:        Installing http_accept_language 2.0.5
remote:        Installing httpclient 2.6.0.1
remote:        Installing curb 0.8.8
remote:        Installing mini_magick 4.2.4
remote:        Installing mixpanel-ruby 2.1.0
remote:        Installing newrelic_rpm 3.12.0.288
remote:        Installing ffi 1.9.8
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Installing kgio 2.9.3
remote:        Installing rb-readline 0.5.2
remote:        Installing redis 3.2.1
remote:        Installing ruby-ole 1.2.11.8
remote:        Installing valuable 0.9.9
remote:        Installing state_machine 1.2.0
remote:        Installing fission 0.5.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.3
remote:        Installing heroku-deflater 0.5.3
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing launchy 2.4.3
remote:        Installing autoparse 0.3.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.12.3
remote:        Installing httparty 0.6.1
remote:        Installing auto_html 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mailchimp-api 2.0.6
remote:        Installing unf 0.1.4
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.1
remote:        Installing compass-core 1.0.3
remote:        Installing compass-import-once 1.0.5
remote:        Installing timers 4.0.1
remote:        Installing faraday 0.9.1
remote:        Installing logging 2.0.0
remote:        Installing pg 0.17.1
remote:        Installing slim 3.0.6
remote:        Installing net-scp 1.2.1
remote:        Installing omniauth 1.2.2
remote:        Installing video_info 2.4.2
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.9.5
remote:        Installing raindrops 0.13.0
remote:        Installing ethon 0.7.3
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing redis-namespace 1.5.2
remote:        Installing spreadsheet 1.0.3
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.1.11
remote:        Installing domain_name 0.5.24
remote:        Installing celluloid 0.16.0
remote:        Installing signet 0.6.1
remote:        Installing oauth2 1.0.0
remote:        Installing fog-core 1.30.0
remote:        Installing omniauth-oauth 1.1.0
remote:        Installing compass 1.0.3
remote:        Installing typhoeus 0.7.1
remote:        Installing to_xls 1.5.3
remote:        Installing actionview 4.1.11
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.1.11
remote:        Installing enumerate_it 1.2.6
remote:        Installing i18n_alchemy 0.2.1
remote:        Installing pundit 1.0.0
remote:        Installing http-cookie 1.0.2
remote:        Installing sidekiq 3.1.4
remote:        Installing googleauth 0.4.1
remote:        Installing omniauth-oauth2 1.3.0
remote:        Installing fog-json 1.0.1
remote:        Installing fog-local 0.2.1
remote:        Installing fog-vmfusion 0.1.0
remote:        Installing omniauth-twitter 1.2.0
remote:        Installing compass-960-plugin 0.10.4
remote:        Installing mixpanel_client 4.1.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.1.11
remote:        Installing active_model_serializers 0.8.0
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.1.11
remote:        Installing carrierwave 0.10.0
remote:        Installing rails-observers 0.1.2
remote:        Installing protected_attributes 1.0.9
remote:        Installing rest-client 1.8.0
remote:        Installing spectator-validates_email 0.2.0
remote:        Installing google-api-client 0.8.6
remote:        Installing omniauth-facebook 2.0.1
remote:        Installing fog-sakuracloud 1.0.1
remote:        Installing fog-brightbox 0.7.1
remote:        Installing fog-serverlove 0.1.2
remote:        Installing fog-softlayer 0.4.6
remote:        Installing fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.1
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.2
remote:        Installing fog-xml 0.1.2
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.1.11
remote:        Using moip 1.0.2 from git://github.com/catarse/moip-ruby.git (at c0225ad)
remote:        Using best_in_place 3.0.0.alpha from git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place (at ee95961)
remote:        Installing unicorn 4.9.0
remote:        Installing has_scope 0.6.0
remote:        Installing kaminari 0.16.3
remote:        Installing railties 4.1.11
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.2
remote:        Installing draper 2.1.0
remote:        Installing routing-filter 0.4.0.1
remote:        Installing simple_form 3.1.0
remote:        Installing ranked-model 0.4.0
remote:        Installing pg_search 1.0.3
remote:        Installing schema_plus 1.8.9
remote:        Installing pagarme 1.10.0
remote:        Installing fog-atmos 0.1.0
remote:        Installing feedjira 1.6.0
remote:        Installing google_drive 1.0.1
remote:        Installing fog-ecloud 0.1.1
remote:        Installing fog-google 0.0.5
remote:        Installing fog-powerdns 0.1.1
remote:        Installing fog-aws 0.2.2
remote:        Installing fog-profitbricks 0.0.2
remote:        Installing fog-radosgw 0.0.4
remote:        Installing fog-riakcs 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-terremark 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-voxel 0.1.0
remote:        Installing mail_form 1.5.1
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing responders 1.1.2
remote:        Installing slim-rails 3.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.1
remote:        Installing rails 4.1.11
remote:        Installing devise 3.4.1
remote:        Installing inherited_resources 1.6.0
remote:        Using catarse_api 0.0.2 from git://github.com/catarse/catarse_api.git (at master)
remote:        Installing compass-rails 2.0.4
remote:        Installing catarse_monkeymail 0.1.6
remote:        Installing catarse_moip 3.2.0
remote:        Installing catarse_settings_db 0.1.1
remote:        Installing catarse_pagarme 2.6.10
remote:        Installing postgres-copy 0.9.2
remote:        Installing dbhero 1.1.8
remote:        Using redactor-rails 0.5.0 from git://github.com/catarse/redactor-rails.git (at master)
remote:        Installing fog 1.30.0
remote:        Installing user_notifier 0.0.5
remote:        Bundle complete! 85 Gemfile dependencies, 192 gems now installed
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from httparty:
remote:        When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
remote:        Post-install message from compass:
remote:        Compass is charityware. If you love it, please donate on our behalf at http://umdf.org/compass Thanks!
remote:        Bundle completed (174.96s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SyntaxError: /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/config/environments/production.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected ...
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/config/environments/production.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected ..., expecting keyword_end
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:405:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_97424fde514623846dbc1198d6b0f17f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to immense-depths-6113.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/immense-depths-6113.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-depths-6113.git'
```

note that my config/application.rb is already set with `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` , so the problem is not that..

Comment: What do you have on/around line 91 of your config/environments/production.rb? That's where the error seems to be coming from, according to the output provided.

Comment: @Zoran , that's what I have:

`90 Rails.application.configure do
91    ...
92    config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
93    …
94 end`

Comment: /Users/iome/my-catarse-app-prova/config/environments/production.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected ..., expecting keyword_end

This clearly indicates that you have a syntax error at line number 93

Comment: @scanE , yes, the problems seems there, but I do not understand what it is.
See my previous comment for the code of that section.
When I try to run it locally, it works fine. but when I try to push it on heroku, it fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have provided on lines 90 through 94, it seems as if the `...` are causing the issue - those are invalid syntax. Try rewriting it like so:

```
config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

Because `Rails.application.configure do` and `end` are specified at the start and end of the file respectively, the extra repetition of those lines is not necessary. This should fix the syntax issue.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to precompile your assets and then commit before you deploy:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```